# Slick argument to find free group in $SO(4)$

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, rotations, free-groups

It is well known that ${\rm SO}(3)$ contains the free group ${\rm F}_2$, so clearly ${\rm SO}(n)$ for $n>3$ does, too. However, the standard proof with ${\rm SO}(3)$  is somewhat annoying (the one sketched [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox)). I've been able to prove in a nice way that if ${\rm SO}(4)$ contains ${\rm F}_2$, then so does ${\rm SO}(3)$, using ${\rm Spin}(4) \cong {\rm Spin}(3) \times {\rm Spin}(3)$ and a lemma about free groups.

It seems there may be a slicker argument that ${\rm SO}(4)$ contains ${\rm F}_2$ compared to ${\rm SO}(3)$, as we have more room to work, in a sense. Is there a nice way to obtain this?

Comment: Maybe some argument using the Ping-Pong lemma could be worked out?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything simpler than picking two rotation and show that they don't relate. What's in your mind, as an example of a *nice way* to build $F_2$?

Comment: I do think finding two rotations that don't relate is the way I want; I just think there's a chance the details could be simpler in SO(4) than in SO(3)

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard argument which works for all algebraic groups - a relation is an algebraic equation, so a generic pair of elements in any algebraic group will generate a free group.

See

*Epstein, D. B. A.*, [**Almost all subgroups of a Lie group are free**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(71)90107-4), J. Algebra 19, 261-262 (1971). [ZBL0222.22012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0222.22012).

Comment: +1, but why doesn't this argument also show the (false) statement that $\mathbb{G}_m^n$ has a free subgroup generated by two elements?

Comment: This sounds good, but I don't think I have the background to understand it: I've read https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49363/cheap-non-constructive-free-group-generating-rotations-for-banach-tarski, but nothing there worked for me. Here I'd prefer an argument that works nicely for SO(4), if one exists

Comment: @hunter It is an alternative: either a relation holds for every pair of of elements, or it holds almost never. Of course, there is a little bit of work to do for any specific group. I will put in the canonical reference in the answer.

Comment: @IgorRivin makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concrete example of a free group in $SO(4)$.
Let $p=\cos\rho+i\sin\rho$ and $q=\cos\rho+j\sin\rho$ two quaternions, where $\rho$ is a transcendental number.
The quaternions $p$ and $q$ generate a free group in the multiplicative group $H$ of quaternions.
Next we should take advantage of the fact that the quaternions are represented by $4\times4$ real matrices, with $p$ and $q$ represented by orthogonal matrices.
Details here: Dekker T. J., Decompositions of sets and spaces. III., Indag. Math 19 (1957): 104-107.

Comment: Is there a nice argument for why those generate a free group?